# Clion cannot import C files (Makefile not updating)

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, clion

Whenever I drag and drop C files into my CLion project, errors occur as the makefile doesn't update. I've tried Reloading the CMake project a bunch of times and, when I try to re-compile the makefile, it says

`Cannot compile file 'Makefile'. Cannot find run configuration for this file`.

So, how can I perform this simple transaction of pasting files over into my CLion project without causing large issues?

Comment: Does [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/08/working-with-makefiles-in-clion-using-compilation-db/) help at all? And when you say `makefile`, you are talking about the traditional unix-style makefiles?

Comment: @Mini That provides some context to why makefiles are used, and yes.

Comment: `makefile`s cannot be compiled.  They are a script, That script can be interpreted via the `make` utility

Comment: @user3629249 I get that, but the script does not update to contain the new files when I import them into the project, despite how they update when I create new files.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit your CMake file and add there the .c/.cpp files you just added to your project.
This will fix what you said.
Nevertheless when I do that, the code inspection stops working and all the errors don't underline.
Let me know if you have the same problem.